# Как сделать более одного TextView в ячейке ListView

Tags: android, java, массивы

Делаю через ArrayAdapter, но в нем получается применить только к одной item_list.

Код неправильный, но все же:

```
 List<String> namelist = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> streetlist = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        namelist.add(jsonObject1.get("name").toString());
                        streetlist.add(jsonObject1.get("adres").toString());
                    }

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.item_list_service, R.id.item_text_service, namelist);

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.item_list_service, R.id.item_text_street_service, streetlist);
   mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
   mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Comment: поставлю плюс

Comment: [попробуй][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106418/how-to-set-adapter-in-case-of-multiple-textviews-per-listview

Comment: @argamidon помогло.

Answer (score 1):

для реализации двух текстовых полей в айтеме ListView вовсе не обязательно делать свой кастомный адаптер - стандартный SimpleAdapter (SimpleCursorAdapter)  отлично с этим справляется , так же он позволяет еще и картинку разместить . Есть и пара-тройка вариантов стандартной разметки в фреймворке Android под это дело , вроде simple_list_item_2.xml / Часто проще и рациональнее воспользоваться готовыми инструментами , чем дублировать имеющююся функциональность увеличивая код .

в качестве [примера](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/listview/hashmap_object.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIdSPSListAdapter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNameSPSListAdapter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Код Адаптера

```
private class CatAdpter extends ArrayAdapter<SpsBD>{

    public CatAdpter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_id_name_adapter, spsBD);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        SpsBD spsBD = getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_id_name_adapter, null);

        }

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvIdSPSListAdapter)).setText(spsBD.idSps);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameSPSListAdapter)).setText(spsBD.nameSps);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: SpsBD? Что это?

Comment: это класс данных

 private class SpsBD{
  public final String idBD;
  public final String idSps;
  public final String nameSps;
  
  public SpsBD(String idBD, String idSps, String nameSps){
   this.idBD = idBD;
   this.idSps = idSps;
   this.nameSps = nameSps;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String toString(){ // преопределение класса
   return this.idBD;
   
  }
 }
ну преопределение корявенькое, но для мой задачи большего не нужно было
http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/