# Набор номера мобильного телефона с Android приложения

Tags: android

Есть активити в котором в ListView отображаются заказы,  в каждом заказе есть поле: номер телефона,  как можно прямо в ListView сделать этот номер ссылкой, при нажатии на которую - набирался бы номер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как сделать более одного TextView в ячейке ListView](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/399859/177345)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)Прописываем в манифесте:  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

2)Код для звонка

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + yourArrayList.getPosition(position).getPhoneNumber()));
startActivity(intent);
```

3) Выше пример для списка с объектами. Если же у вас каждый элемент это одно текстовое поле со всей инфой, то надо бы передеалть тогда. Ну или как максимум поиграться с `subString`

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:autoLink="phone" />
```

Данный код вам в помощь, а именно флаг `android:autoLink="phone"` Он задаёт параметр, что в данном TextView может находиться телефон и по его нахождении он будет выделен цветом и будет кликабельным, если будет баговаться, то попробуйте разделить текст на несколько TextView и добавить `android:autoLink="phone"` только в тот, в котором будет чисто номер телефона написан. Также стоит обратить внимание, что данный флаг может не сработать и телефон может быть не кликабельным, если будет неизвестный формат телефона, поэтому телефоны должны быть адекватного формата, а не **fffapoga** и что-то подобное

Comment: а если я вынесу номер в отдельный TextView , но в моем ListView как один item смогут быть  TextView  с номером и TextView  с остальной инфой о заказе?

Comment: @KirillStoianov Об этом я и писал выше, можно так сделать, только добавьте флаг в тот TextView, который будет содержать номер телефона

Answer (score 0):

Самый примитивный способ - это поместить номер в отдельный *TextView* с специальным стилем(подчеркивание и синий как ссылка), на него повесить *OnClickListener*,а дальше обычная работа с *TelephoneManager*(или чем то такими). Посмотри книгу Алексея Голощапова "Google Android Создание приложения для смартфонов и планшетных ПК".

Comment: а что то типа тега " tel:// "  есть такое? или это только для iOS ?

Comment: Голощапов страница 565(2013 года книга издания). Цитата"Сам Extr-параметр для объекта интентн - не просто телефонный номер, а объект URI,имеет следующий формат
tel:номер_абонента
...."  Полностью код писать не буду, там все очень примитивно. Можно в две строчки этот вызов осуществить

Comment: Нашел в сети только за 2015 г но не нашел в содержании то что мне надо! можете поделится ссылкой на книгу 2013 года, или подсказать хоть что нужно искать в содержании?

Comment: Пример кода(инициирует исходящий звонок):
*String pnoneNum ="5554"; Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNum); Intent intent = new Intent(intent.ACTION_DIAL,uri); startActivity(intent);* В файл манифеста не забудь добавить *android.permission.CALL_PHONE*

Comment: Глава "Обработка телефонных вызовов", суб. глава: "Вызов телефонного абонента из приложения"

Comment: спасибо за пример, а не подскажите где можно найти ту самую книгу о которой вы говорили? Только что обратил внимание что под видом ссылки на книгу о которой говорили вы, лежал совсем другой учебник по Android:)

Comment: К сожалению, не могу сказать где достать эту книгу. Моя в бумажном экземпляре(сейчас перед глазами) была куплена в 2013 году. Буду дома - посмотрю возможно есть в электронном виде, тогда поделюсь ссылкой.