# Набор номера +7978.. (Unity 5) Android

Tags: android

Как сделать так: что в игре у меня есть кнопка, нажав на нее должно открыться меню с номером абонента +7978.., и далее нажав позвонить, будет переводить уже на звонок человеку на Android

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473147/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069340/how-to-start-an-android-activity-from-a-unity-application