# Нужно несколько textView вывести в listView. Сейчас выводятся только заголовки. Как правильно сделать адаптер?

Tags: java, android, json, listview

```
package com.example.worker.webparsing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // благодоря этому классу мы будем разбирать данные на куски
    public Elements storyTitle;
    public Elements storyText;

    // то в чем будем хранить данные пока не передадим адаптеру
    public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Listview Adapter для вывода данных
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // определение данных
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // запрос к нашему отдельному поток на выборку данных
        new NewThread().execute();

        // Добавляем данные для ListView
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.text1, titleList);
    }

    // внутрений класс который делает запросы
    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Метод выполняющий запрос в фоне, в версиях выше 4 андроида, запросы в главном потоке выполнять
        // нельзя, поэтому все что вам нужно выполнять - выносите в отдельный тред
        @Override
        protected  String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            String url = "https://news.yandex.ru/?lang=ru";

            // класс который захватывает страницу
            Document doc;

            try {
                // определяем откуда будем воровать данные
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // задаем с какого места, я выбрал заголовке статей
                storyTitle = doc.select(".story__title");
                storyText = doc.select(".story__text");

                // чистим наш аррей лист для того что бы заполнить
                titleList.clear();
                textList.clear();

                // и в цикле захватываем все данные какие есть на странице
                for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element storyTitles : storyTitle) {
                    // записываем в аррей лист
                    titleList.add(storyTitles.text());
                }
                for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element storyTexts: storyText) {
                    // записываем в аррей лист
                    textList.add(storyTexts.text());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // ничего не возвращаем потому что я так захотел)
            return  null;
         }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // после запроса обновляем листвью
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415462/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. Свой адаптер написать
2. Свою разметку сделать
3. в `getView()` адаптера элементам своей разметки присвоить текст

А потом переделать всё это на `RecyclerView` т.к. `ListView` устарел.

Comment: Нет никаких отметок о том, что `ListView` - deprecated. По сути `ListView` и `RecyclerView` хоть внешне и похожи, но разные виджеты и у каждого своя область применения.

Comment: @pavlofff, а какую область применения для `ListView` вы можете назвать? Так чтобы его применение было предпочтительнее `RecyclerView`?

Comment: По этому вопросу достаточно написано уже. В основном, если в своем списке вы не используете все эти `LayoutManager`, `ItemAnimator`, `ItemDecorator` - вам нужен простой такой список, то `RecyclerView` во много "беднее" в стоке. У него нет готовых адаптеров, слушателей и отсутствуют многие методы, которые есть в `ListView` и его адаптерах, так же  xml-атрибуты, как например простая смена дивидера. Все это можно написать .. самому!! НО ЗАЧЕМ, если уже есть готовый виджет, с большим набором готовых решений, а преимущества нового вы не используете.

Comment: @pavlofff, посыл понял, но видел не раз (как и в этом вопросе), что после использования простых этих примеров приходят и спрашивают про усложнение (по вопросу в неделю, по моему). Также не раз видел проблемы у людей с присваиваниями слушателей событий и их конфликтами (один в адаптере, другой вне). Плюс (по мне главное) слушатель скрола у `RecyclerView` гораздо лучше. Ну и всякие `LayoutManager` настолько полезны, что от `ListView` можно отказаться, пусть он в некоторых случаях быстрее пишется, чем тоже самое для `RecyclerView`.